# How to create persistent symbolic links and fix permissions to use the raw print?

Tags: usb, permissions, printing, udev

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and I want create persistent symbolic links for my USB printers. In other hand, I can't write to these devices:

```
$ ls -l /dev/usb/lp*
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 jun 25 14:17 /dev/usb/lp0
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 1 jun 25 14:17 /dev/usb/lp1
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 2 jun 25 14:17 /dev/usb/lp2
```

- How i can change this permission to `666`?
- How can i create the persistent symbolic links using:

  ```
  sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
  ```

  This is its contents:

  ```
  # Low-level USB device add trigger
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="07", ATTR{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01", TAG+="udev-configure-printer", RUN+="udev-configure-printer add %p"
  # Low-level USB device remove trigger
  ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:0701*:*", RUN+="udev-configure-printer remove %p"

  # printer1
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="3uL8tBCQUl2hMhoY12Vf", SYMLINK+="caliente"
  # printer2
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="JGHE24ikKU7plwR8x3c6", SYMLINK+="bar"
  # printer3
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="xVc0EQQd3nZzq6ziv8SS", SYMLINK+="fria"
  ```

  As the current state, The symbolic links which are created:

  ```
  ls -l /dev/bar 
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 jun 25 14:12 /dev/bar -> bus/usb/003/002
  ```

  But when i try to print in the command line i get this:

  ```
  echo "hi" >> /dev/bar
  bash: /dev/bar: Permission denied
  ```

  I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Well to change `crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 jun 25 14:17 /dev/usb/lp0`, i go to `sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` to the line `KERNEL=="lp[0-9]*", GROUP="lp", MODE="0777"` and add the last part `MODE="0777"` and now i got `ls -l /dev/usb/lp*
crwxrwxrwx 1 root lp 180, 0 jun 25 20:48 /dev/usb/lp0` but i need the symbolic link permission to be persistence with the printer name.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Xubuntu 14.04 you need create a rules file for printers in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

   ```
   $ sudo nano 90-printers.rules
   ```
2. In this file add the follow code:

   ```
   ACTION=="remove", GOTO="persistent_printer_end"

   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id"
   ENV{ID_TYPE}!="printer", GOTO="persistent_printer_end"

   ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="lp/printers/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}"

   LABEL="persistent_printer_end"
   ```

Then you can see the new and persistent symbolic links in the following paths:

```
$ ls -l /dev/lp/printers
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 jul 21 14:42 usb-Jolimark_USB_Printer_JGHE24ikKU7plwR8x3c6 -> ../../usb/lp2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 jul 21 14:42 usb-Jolimark_USB_Printer_MQrvZsOINprsF6dIEor9 -> ../../usb/lp0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 jul 21 14:42 usb-Jolimark_USB_Printer_xVc0EQQd3nZzq6ziv8SS -> ../../usb/lp1
```

These point to the following paths:

```
$ ls -l /dev/usb/lp*
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 jul 21 14:42 /dev/usb/lp0
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 1 jul 21 14:42 /dev/usb/lp1
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 2 jul 21 14:42 /dev/usb/lp2
```

Comment: Thank you elgastelum for sharing this. I don't work much with printers. I would ask you if you still need to tune this udev rule I may help. If it works well, you can accept your own .answer. See http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer